# How to check if a member variable is a Map with Reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I know that I can check for a List by using

```
 Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
```

But how can I check if a Field in a class is an implementation of a Map?

```
    void myMethod(Class<?> classToCheck) {
        Field[] fields = classToCheck.getDeclaredFields();

        for(Field field:fields) {
           // check if field implements Map<?,?>
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about `instanceof`?

Comment: `Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())`?

Comment: @Keppil ahh stupid me I forgot the "class" when I tried Map.isAssignableFrom(...) yes this should do the trick - thx!

Comment: @feuerball getType() is instance of Class and the returned object of the field could be null which is not an instance of Map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Field#getType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()) method which will return you the `Class<?>` of the field.

```
for(Field field:fields) {
    Class<?> clazz = field.getType();
    boolean isItAMap = Map.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
```

Comment: This is the same as @kocko answered.

Comment: @feuerball: It is now after kocko edited his answer, it wasn't before.

Comment: @feuerball:- Yes I got the human verification check which delayed me to answer!

Comment: @feuerball there is no such thing that two people can't have a same answer.